# WCF service on IIS 7, Erreur HTTP 404.3 - Not Found

Tags: c#, wcf, iis, iis-7

I know this question was asked many times, i have read all of them and tried all of the answers suggested, but nothing worked for me.
I'm trying to host my WCF service on IIS7/Windows Server 2008, i'm facing the error bellow:

```
HTTP Error 404.3 - Not Found

The page you are requesting cannot be served because of the extension configuration. If the page is a script, add a handler. If the file should be downloaded, add a MIME map.
```

i have run the command bellow

```
 C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.0\Windows Communication Foundation\ServiceModelReg.exe -i
```

which is supposed to install WCF and add all the necessary MIME types, but still the same problem.

Also i made sure ASP.NET is installed by executing the command bellow:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe -i
```

But still the same problem.

So i added manually .svc on MIME types using type application/octet-stream, the result was the content of my website service:

```
`<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="SAGBService.SAGBService"%`>
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ok i solved the problem by following the steps as bellow:

-Execute these commands :

```
cd\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319
aspnet_regiis.exe -iru
iisreset
```

- Open a command prompt window and type start inetmgr to open the Internet Information Services (IIS) MMC snap-in

-In the left pane, expand the node with the computer's name, then expand the Web Sites node, and then select the Default Web Site.

-Double click Handler mappings in the Features View.

-In the list of application mappings, verify that the .svc file is mapped to the aspnet_isapi.dll. If the file has not been mapped:

```
    * Click Add Managed Handler.

    * Type *.svc into the Request path.

    * Type System.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceHttpHandlerFactory, System.ServiceModel.Activation, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35 into the Type textbox.

    * Type svc-Integrated-4.0 into the Name: textbox.

    * Click OK.

    * Click Add Script Map.

    * Type *.svc into the Request path.

    * Type %SystemRoot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll into the Executable: text box.

    * Type svc-ISAPI-2.0 into the Name: text box.

    * Click OK.
```

- Go to modules and delete ServiceModel.